# How do I use a private Dockerhub image from my Synology NAS

Tags: docker, dockerhub, synology

Usually I have a public Dockerfile  that I build with public DockerHub repository (songkong/songkong), then I can run it on my Synology by just searching for the tag in the registry

[image: Public Image]

but I am making some changes in my private DockerHub repo (songkong/songkongdockerdev) before public release. I have built image okay in Dockerhub, and I guess I use *Image/Add from Url* in Synology

[image]

but I cannot get the syntax correct for the *Hub Page or Repository* field, I tried a few things such as

- https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/songkong/songkongdockerdev
- songkong/songkongdockerdev
- songkongdockerdev/latest

what should it be ?

Comment: Try `docker.io/songkong/songkongdockerdev`

Comment: @kitt I tried it and it says Registry received bad result

Comment: Try this `https://index.docker.io/v1/songkong/songkongdockerdev`

Comment: @ChenA. didnt work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem for a long time.

Instead of https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/songkong/songkongdockerdev
use https://hub.docker.com/r/songkong/songkongdockerdev

Fill in your docker hub username and password.

Comment: This solution does not seem to work for me now, I get "Registry returned bad result" error popup on Synolgy UI. Any other suggestions?

Comment: This also doesn't work for me, and I also tried @Rick-Penabella 's URL which has `https://repository.*` as a differentator.
I've also make my repo public temporarily

Comment: @BrainArchitect see my new answer below. It may help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it properly from terminal on Synology bypassing GUI limitations. For example to pull from custom registry (in this case Microsoft one) you can execute it like you would in docker cli

```
root@synology:~# docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/powershell
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from powershell
7595c8c21622: Pull complete
d13af8ca898f: Pull complete
70799171ddba: Pull complete
b6c12202c5ef: Pull complete
6c95148a5c40: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:e5fd412f741be3eaab244635f73bbec9b44f4546f3182b4cc5fa9dc90360b1b8
Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest
```

Answer (score 3):

This format worked for me in Docker Synology GUI under docker - images:

URL: [https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/{accountname}/{reponame}/](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/%7Baccountname%7D/%7Breponame%7D/)

then your username & password

Answer (score 2):

I cannot get private repo to works, so i opted for making the image public for a minute then add it on synology, then make it private again after has downloaded the image.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing else worked for me but this did. Hopefully it helps others.
Instead of searching for my repo in the registry, I was able to Add an Image from Url directly.

1. Click on Image
2. Click Add
3. Click Add From URL
4. use this format for the "Hub Page of Repository URL": `https://hub.docker.com/r/{username}/{reponame}`
5. Put in username and password
6. I needed to make my repo public (temporarily) for this to work.